# How to use "setTimeout" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#Error").animate({margin:"-50px"});
        $("#errorCloseholder").animate({margin:"-50px"});
      }, 2000);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

This code, assisted with jQuery, is supposed to hide some elements after 2 seconds.

Unfortunately, this code isn't working. Does it have to do with jQuery? Or do I have some kind of syntax error?

The elements have an id of Error and errorCloseholder, and they are both error messages that are to be hidden after 2 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with this `};);`.

Comment: ^ Haha it's note <code></code> just press "that button" on the left of 1 on the keyboard.

Comment: you don't need the `window.` prefix here; that mentioned, out of curiosity: why are you using a timeout here, rather than a CSS class with a transition delay?

Comment: Vote to close as typo

Comment: @kuma keyboard map can depend on wich country do you leave `I found it : Azerty keyboard -> altgr+7+space` french accent ```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error at the end of your `.ready()` function.

```
      };); //this one remove the first semi colon
   </script>
</head>
```

<kbd>[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/VSbKx/)</kbd>

Comment: the problem is in the wink -----> ;)

Comment: how do you put code tag in comments ?

Comment: ^ Haha it's note <code></code> just press "that button" on the left of 1 on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#Error").animate({margin: "-50px"});
    $("#errorCloseholder").animate({margin: "-50px"});
  }, 2000);
});
```

Remove **';'** from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.load()` event here...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#Error").animate({margin:"-50px"});
        $("#errorCloseholder").animate({margin:"-50px"});
    }, 2000);
   });
});
```

Comment: what - > $(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function(){      Why ?

Comment: I thought that animations would be done before the resources getting loaded.. So users could not see it..

Comment: $(document).ready(// is not enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have one too many semi-colons. Try removing the second to last one in your ".ready" function and see if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` method that calls a function after a defined no. of milliseconds.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
  var x = document.getElementById("txt");

  setTimeout(function(){x.value="2 seconds"},2000);<br/>
  setTimeout(function(){x.value="4 seconds"},4000);<br/>
  setTimeout(function(){x.value="6 seconds"},6000);<br/>
}
```

Here, "txt" is the label or textbox.
Result will be like this:
2 seconds
4 seconds
6 seconds